# Using variables between tasks in fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I have an issue with fabfile. I have next next script

```
temp = []

    rolesdef = { server1: [user@server.com],
server2: [user@server2.com, user@server3.com]
}

@task
@roles('server1')
def first():
  ...do something...
  temp = something

@task
@roles('server2')
@parallel
def second():
  ...do something...
  run(temp)
```

How can I use "temp" in second() which has been defined in first()?
Also, I want to execute first() on server1 and second() on server2 during one execution of fabfile.

Should I to use execute() but how can I setup password for auth in a line with "hosts"?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use env to share temp, and the with_setting decorator to change password and user -

```
from fabric.api import env
from fabric.decorators import with_settings, roles, task

rolesdef = { "server1": ["server.com"],
"server2": ["server2.com", "server3.com"]
}
connection = { "server1": {"user": "user1", "password": "123"},
"server2": {"user": "user2", "password": "456"}
}

@task
@roles('server1')
@with_settings(**connection["server1"])
def first():
  ...do something...
  env.temp = something

@task
@roles('server2')
@with_settings(**connection["server2"])
@parallel
def second():
  ...do something...
  run(env.temp)
```